# How to call a method from parent view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a parent view (table) that passes a detail object to the child view (table).

The parent view has a network request that gets data and passes data to the child view.

I want to be able to update the data when I'm in the child view. I think I need to call the parent view's network request method while viewing the child view, and update the child table.   Is this possible?

In Parent VC:

```
- (void)fetchAppointmentsForVisibleDate {   
    self.appointmentArray = [DataSource getTodayData:self.visibleDate];

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:50];
    for (NSDictionary *appointment in self.appointmentArray)
    {
        [array addObject: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@", [appointment objectForKey:@"scheduled_time"], [appointment objectForKey:@"patient"]]];
    }
    self.listData = array;

    [self.appointmentTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ChildVC *vc = [Child VC alloc]initWithNib@"ChildVC"];
    vc.appointmentDictionary = [self.appointmentArray objectAtIndex:path.row];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your network request is bound to be called by parent view.

If its just a method you can set the delegate of your child to the parent.
i.e in the parent view you can do

create child object and just do

```
child.delegate=self;
```

and call your network method from child

i.e      [delegate networkMethod];

Comment: Well the network request in the parent view is a method that gets a NSDictionary, then passes an object from this dictionary to child view.  If I do this delegate, and call the method, will it still update the data in the child view?

Comment: When you are calling the child view from the parent just call it and send the NSDictionary to child.Use that NSDictionary(i.e save it somewhere in child view) it will work perfect. But when you want to call that method from child just use the delegate which was set in the parentView at the time calling the childView. you can easily call that function and can get the desired help.

Comment: I just added the netowrk request and how the data is passed from Parent to Child VC.

Comment: one doubt are you able to set the child dictionary with this line. is that line is working.                                   vc.appointmentDictionary = [self.appointmentArray objectAtIndex:path.row];

Comment: `vc.appointmentDictionary = [self.appointmentArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` works fine.  What do you mean?

Comment: Wondering why you added multiple answers for same question

Comment: Sorry @TJ The answer was in 2011 and i was pretty new to SO.. :P

Answer (score 0):

Ok so lets assume that you code works do the following.

in the .h file of your child class add

```
 {
    id delegate;
 }
  @property(nonatomic,retain) id delegate;
```

in the .m file of you child do all the needed things like synthesize it etc.

Now in you parent class do

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
ChildVC *vc = [Child VC alloc]initWithNib@"ChildVC"];
 vc.delegate=self; //here you set the delegate of your child.

vc.appointmentDictionary = [self.appointmentArray objectAtIndex:path.row];
}
```

Now in your child .m class if you want to call any function that resides in parent view class then just do.

```
 [delegate myNetworkFunction] //it will give warning but dont worry
```

you can also pass argument if you want

```
 [delegate myNetworkFunction:myArgument];
```

Comment: This works with calling my function.  But look at the sample code I posted.  Even if I call the fetch method from my child VC, how do I get it to pass the new updated dictionary to the child view without selecting the row again since it is usally passed using the `didSelectRowAtIndex` method.

Comment: ok in the child class declare an int variable that will store the current row that is being selected.do all that code in didSelectRowAtIndex and also in the parent view create a new function that will return the updated dictionary of you child class. Now in the child class you have row saved .Now call the newly created function -(NSDictionary *)updateDict:(int)row- in parent view that will return "return([self.appointmentArray objectAtindex:row])" and in the child just do like this appointmentDictionary=[delegate updateDict:row];